# Реализация движения героя в игре. Cocos2d xcode obj-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, разработка-игр, cocos2d, spritekit

Помогите разобраться с управлением героя. Есть сцена, в неё помещен герой, кинул на сцену 3 кнопки(CCNode), для движения на лево, направо и прыжок. Управление работает, но когда герой проходит по "карте" дальше, то при отпускании и следующем нажатии на какую либо кнопку не происходит движение... Как бы фрэйм остаётся в начале карты, и тоуч как бы уже приходится не на кнопку, а спрайт кнопки стоят нормально, они двигаются вместе с героем. Работаю в xcode и spritekit. Код представляю ниже:

```
 -(void)update:(CCTime)delta{
    float rad = _mainHero.rotation *(M_PI/180);
    if (clickedRight) {
        NSLog(@"нажата кнопка");
   _mainHero.position = ccpAdd(_mainHero.position, ccp(delta *80, 0));
    }else if (clickedLeft) {
        _mainHero.position = ccpAdd(_mainHero.position, ccp(-1*delta *80, 0));
    }
    if (clickedJump) {
        _mainHero.position = ccpAdd(_mainHero.position, ccp(sin(rad) * delta *150, cos(rad)*delta*150));
    }

}




  -(void)touchMoved:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event{
    _follow = [CCActionFollow actionWithTarget:_mainHero worldBoundary:self.boundingBox];
    [_contentNode runAction:_follow];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_contentNode];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_btnRight boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        CCLOG(@"пробежалась по кнопке НАПРАВО !!!!---->>>");

    }

    self.position = ccp(0, 0);

 if (CGRectContainsPoint([_btnRight boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        clickedRight = YES;
        CCLOG(@"нажато на кнопку НАПРАВО !!!!---->>>");

        clickedLeft = NO;
        clickedJump = NO;

   }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_btnLeft boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        clickedLeft = YES;
        clickedRight = NO;
        clickedJump = NO;
        CCLOG(@"нажато на кнопку НАЛЕВО !!!!---->>>");

    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_btnJump boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        clickedJump = YES;
        clickedLeft = NO;
        clickedRight = NO;
        CCLOG(@"нажато на кнопку ПРЫЖОК !!!!---->>>");
    }



}
-(void)touchEnded:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event{
     clickedJump = NO;
    clickedLeft = NO;
    clickedRight = NO;

    CCLOG(@"END---->>>");


}



- (void)touchBegan:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event {
    [self launchPenguin];
    // ensure followed object is in visible are when starting

    _follow = [CCActionFollow actionWithTarget:_mainHero worldBoundary:self.boundingBox];
    [_contentNode runAction:_follow];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_contentNode];
    }



-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {


        self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

        clickedJump = NO;
        clickedLeft = NO;
        clickedRight = NO;

        self.position = ccp(0, 0);
        _follow = [CCActionFollow actionWithTarget:_mainHero worldBoundary:self.boundingBox];
        [_contentNode runAction:_follow];
           }
    return  self;
}
```

Comment: https://www.makeschool.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/creating-two-levels делал по тутору, там вот кнопку РЕСТАРТ они делали, кнопку Я тоже добавлял, она двигалась вместе с героем, и работало событие еёшние, но с кнопками движени не получилось реализовать, так как не понял как сделать чтобы герой двигался пока кнопка нажата...